# Calculate 1DPlot, determine the maxima and their distances between each other

Tags: c++, opencv, maxima

I want to create a 1D plot from an image. Then I want to determine the maxima and their distances to each other in c++.
I am looking for some tips on how I could approach this.

I load the image as cv::Mat. In opencv I have searched, but only found the histogram function, which is wrong. I want to get a cross section of the image - from left to right.
does anyone have an idea ?

Well I have the following picture:

[image: original_image]

From this I want to create a 1D plot like in the following picture (I created the plot in ImageJ).

[image: 1dPlot]

Here you can see the maxima (I could refine it with "smooth").
I want to determine the positions of these maxima and then the distances between them.

I have to get to the 1D plot somehow. I suppose I can get to the maxima with a derivation?

++++++++++ UPDATE ++++++++++

Now i wrote this to get an 1D Plot:

```cpp
    cv::Mat img= cv::imread(imgFile.toStdString(), cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    uint8_t* data = img.data;
    int width = img.cols;
    int height = img.rows;
    int stride = img.step;
    std::vector<double> vPlot(width, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            uint8_t val = data[ i * stride + j];
            vPlot[j]=vPlot[j] + val;
        }
    }
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("path\\plot.csv");
    for(int i = 0; i < vPlot.size(); i++){
        file << vPlot[i];
        file << ";";
    }
    file.close();
```

When i plot this in excel i got this:
[image: excel plot]

Thats looks not so smooth as in ImageJ. Did i something wrong?
I need it like in the Plot of ImageJ - more smooth.

ok I got it:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < vPlot.size(); i++) {
        vPlot[i] = vPlot[i] / height;
    }
```

[image: smoothplot]

Ok but i don't know how to get the maxima an distances.
When i have the local maxima (i don't know how), i can calculate the distance between them with the index of the vetcor elements.

**Has anybody an idea to get the local Maxima out of the vector, that I plot above ?**

Now o wrote this to find the maxima:

```cpp
// find maxima 
    std::vector<int> idxMax;
    int flag = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < avg.size(); i++){

        double diff = avg[i] - avg[i-1];

        if(diff < 0){
            if(flag>0){
                idxMax.push_back(i);
                flag = -1;

            }
        }
        if(diff >= 0){
            if(flag<=0){
                flag = 1;

            }
        }
    }
```

But more maxima are found than wanted. The length of the vector varies and also the number of peaks. These can be close together or far away. They are also not always the same height, as can be seen in the picture

Comment: Now I had an idea right away. Maybe I have to go over the picture with a pointer and sum up the values for each column. Line by line. Then i have maybe a vector of values. from x=0 to x=image.width.
I try to program this now and give an update.

Comment: `vPlot[j]=++val;` - what do you intend to do with this line? I assume it does not what you think it does. In the end, it will give you the last image row (1 added to all values). And dividing by a constant `height` cannot really smooth that. So I am a bit surprised by your output. Is this really the code you used? How can a tip between 200 and 250 become something between 120 and 140 when dividing by the image height?

Comment: yes i corrected it. Thanks i will update the code. I use this code (with the correction of vplot[j] =++val;

Comment: ImageJ Plotter docu says this :"For rectangular selections, the plot displays a “column average plot”, where the x-axis represents the horizontal distance through the selection and the y-axis the vertically averaged pixel intensity. " So thats why i divided by height (height is the number of values per column)